# Facebook login issues with access token

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

On my React project, I am using [react-facebook-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login) package. I just went live and out of ~20 users, 2 of them cannot log in. They say that they filled their credentials, allowed facebook to login into my system, and `/login` page just refreshed itself, nothing happens. It seems that the error they are getting is:

```
You are overriding current access token, that means some other app is expecting different access token and you will probably break things. Please consider passing access_token directly to API parameters instead of overriding the global settings
```

What might cause this? I went through different answers and nothing helped me yet to solve the issue. I tried:

1) Creating test account on Facebook developer console. Error is sometimes displayed in console, sometimes not, but it goes through nonetheless.

2) Whitelisting everything related to my domain

3) I submitted my documents for `Individual Verification`, but others say it doesn't help

This is how my login procedure looks like:

```
<FacebookLogin
  appId="<this is app id>"
  autoLoad={true}
  fields="name,email"
  callback={responseFacebook}
  disableMobileRedirect={true}
/>
```

I have `disableMobileRedirect` [due to known bug](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login/issues/175).

This is my `responseFacebook` function:

```
const responseFacebook = response => {
    if (response.name && response.email && response.userID) {
      const isMw = attemptMwMember(response.email);

      Cookies.set("name", response.name);
      Cookies.set("email", response.email);
      Cookies.set("isLoggedIn", true);
      if (isMw) {
        Cookies.set("mw", true);
      } else {
        Cookies.set("mw", false);
      }

      navigate(`/`);
      window.location.reload(false);
    }
  };
```

Basically I use these cookies to know if user is logged in and in my application I have `private` and `public` routes. `Private` ones are checking if all of the above cookies are present, if not- redirects to `/login`.

Anyone had this issue? I am a bit going nuts here, especially when it works for majority but not for some users.

Comment: Did you find a react js solution for this? Its giving me nightmares